# How to draw a trapezium/trapezoid with css3?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

When you go to the page http://m.google.com using Mobile Safari, you will see the beautiful bar on the top of the page.

I wanna draw some trapeziums (US: trapezoids) like that, but I don't know how.  Should I use css3 3d transform?  If you have a good method to achieve it please tell me.

Comment: You mean the navigation bar? It's an image: http://www.google.com/mobile/images/mgc3/mgc-body-toolbar-bg-banner.png

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but isn't it just a gradient image applied to body tag? If so you could use css3 gradients...I don't know what "trapeziums" means.

Comment: In the US, we say "trapezoid" for a quadrilateral with one pair of parallel sides, and "trapezium" for a quadrilateral with no parallel sides.  Outside the US, "trapezium" = US::"trapezoid", and US::"trapezium" is just "irregular".  Knowing is half the battle~

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use some CSS like this:

```css
#trapezoid {
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="trapezoid"></div>
```

It is really cool to make all this shapes, Take a look to more nice shapes at:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

EDIT:
This css is applied to a DIV element

Comment: thank you very much!!!I had seen this website before but i forgot it last night!I have solved the problem.Really Thank You!

Comment: you're welcome, it is one of my favorite sites, you can find a lot of useful information there.

Comment: sir, I want responsive trapziod shape. can you tell me anything about it?

Comment: @Kishan: Check out this answer for responsive trapezoid http://stackoverflow.com/a/26628030/933633

Answer (score 88):

As this is quite old now, I feel it could use with some new updated answers with some new technologies.

### CSS Transform Perspective

```css
.trapezoid {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  transform: perspective(10px) rotateX(1deg);
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezoid"></div>
```

### SVG

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="20%">
  <path d="M3,0 L17,0 L20,20 L0,20z" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

### Canvas

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(30, 0);
ctx.lineTo(170, 0);
ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
ctx.lineTo(0, 200);
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: first part should be top answer

Comment: I like the accepted answer but as where I'm using this INSIDE of a keyframe `animation` I had to use a css `transform` which was included in this answer

Comment: This also throws a trapezoid  `box-shadow`!

Comment: If you don't want to apply the same transformation on text inside the trapezoid, remember to reverse the transformation for the inner element: `transform: perspective(10px) rotateX(-1deg);`

Answer (score 11):

## Simple way

To draw any shape, you can use the CSS **clip-path** property like below.

You can use free online editors to generate this code (ex: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

```
.trapezoid {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 84% 41%, 16% 41%);
}
```

## With reusable code

If you want it more adaptative, you can define a **Sass mixin** like :

```
@mixin trapezoid ($top-width, $bottom-width, $height) {
    $width: max($top-width, $bottom-width);
    $half-width-diff: abs($top-width - $bottom-width) / 2;

    $top-left-x: 0;
    $top-right-x: 0;
    $bottom-left-x: 0;
    $bottom-right-x: 0;

    @if ($top-width > $bottom-width) {
        $top-left-x: 0;
        $top-right-x: $top-width;
        $bottom-left-x: $half-width-diff;
        $bottom-right-x: $top-width - $half-width-diff;
    } @else {
        $top-left-x: $half-width-diff;
        $top-right-x: $bottom-width - $half-width-diff;
        $bottom-left-x: 0;
        $bottom-right-x: $bottom-width;
    }

    clip-path: polygon($top-left-x 0, $top-right-x 0, $bottom-right-x $height, $bottom-left-x $height);
    
    width: $width;
    height: $height;
}
```

And then use it for the desired element like this (here parameters are $top-width, $bottom-width, $height) :

```
.my-div {
    @include trapezoid(8rem, 6rem, 2rem);
}
```

Comment: Note that an outer shadow on the div will appear outside the clipping area, thus it won't be visible.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question... but I want to add a method that has not been mentioned. It is possible to draw triangles with gradients of half color half transparent, and then it is possible to build a trapezoid from 3 gradient shapes. Here is an example code, the 3 blocks drawed in different colors for better understanding:

```css
#example {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(to top left, red 0 50%, transparent 50% 100%),
        linear-gradient(to top right, green 0 50%, transparent 50% 100%),
        linear-gradient(blue 0 100%);
    background-size:
        20% 100%, 20% 100%, 60% 100%;
    background-position:
        left top, right top, center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options available to you. You can just plain use an image, draw something with svg or distort a regular div with css transforms. An image would be easiest, and would work across all browsers. Drawing in svg is a bit more complex and is not guaranteed to work across the board.

Using css transforms on the other hand would mean you'd have to have your shape divs in the background, then layer the actual text over them in another element to that the text isn't skewed as well. Again, browser support isn't guaranteed.