# Repositioning Navbar and links

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap and was wondering how to reposition the navbar and also how to reposition the links in the navbar.

Any help welcome.

[image]

Comment: That image doesn't explain what you're trying to accomplish. Please elaborate.

Comment: Please add more info about what you are trying to do, and what you have tried already, or else we really can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

This question shows *very little* by the way of effort, but just to get you *started*, here's a little customization of the [Bootstrap Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).  If this doesn't meet your needs, please use it as a starting point to ask a more focused question in the future.

### [Here's a Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/deE3j/)

[image: screenshot]

I've added all the links to the `navbar-collapse` section. I've hidden the `navbar-header` with `visible-xs` so it doesn't interfere with position of the other links in the open position and will only show up once collapsed on a small screen.

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">

        <!-- Header -->
        <div class="navbar-header visible-xs">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 3.0 Skeleton</a>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Navbar Links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#Courses">Courses</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#About">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#News">News</a></li>
                <li class='trapezoid'><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Awards">Awards</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Projects">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can style the home link to be a little more distinguished.  I used this [trapezoid code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7920754/1366033):

```css
li.trapezoid  {
    border-bottom: 50px solid #e7e7e7;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
li.trapezoid a {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```