# Quadrilateral Trapezoid in CSS

Tags: html, css, shapes

Hey< I am trying to recreate this image in CSS.

[image]

So far I have this:

https://jsfiddle.net/mstppvwe/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#red ">
            <div class="red">
                <p>=FIRST-</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#orange">
            <div class="orange">
                <p>--SECOND--</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#blue">
            <div class="blue">
                <p>--- THIRDBOX ---</p>
            </div>              
        </a>
```

CSS:

```
<div id="container">
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#red ">
            <div class="red">
                <p>=FIRST-</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#orange">
            <div class="orange">
                <p>--SECOND--</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#blue">
            <div class="blue">
                <p>--- THIRDBOX ---</p>
            </div>              
        </a>
```

I've played with borders and also tried the transform, to no avail!

The whole bar needs to be a hyperlink with an overlay of text as shown in my HTML mockup

Can someone please help. Thanks!

Comment: What does "tried the transform" mean? What did you try exactly?

Comment: Have you also looked at **[this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920754/how-to-draw-a-trapezium-trapezoid-with-css3)**?

Comment: I had looked at that post @evolutionxbox , but I can only see how to achieve a triangular shape or complete trapezoid.

Comment: You can reduce the right border to achieve your desired shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `:before` pseudo element on each div.

```css
#container {
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  right: 20px;
}
.three-bars,
.red,
.orange,
.blue {
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}
.red {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #da3421;
}
.orange {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #ec9a4c;
}
.blue {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #5ab7c4;
}
a > div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 70px 70px;
  border-color: transparent transparent black;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.red:before {
  border-color: transparent transparent #da3421;
}
.orange:before {
  border-color: transparent transparent #ec9a4c;
}
.blue:before {
  border-color: transparent transparent #5ab7c4;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a class="page-scroll" href="#red ">
    <div class="red">
      <p>=FIRST-</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="page-scroll" href="#orange">
    <div class="orange">
      <p>--SECOND--</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="page-scroll" href="#blue">
    <div class="blue">
      <p>--- THIRDBOX ---</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks. Just a bit of strange behaviour when I incororate Bootstrap, but I can figure that out