# CSS button idea

Tags: css

I need to create this button with CSS.
I had no idea how I'm gonna do it so I'm trying to reach for help
any idea?
[image: css button]

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: This link will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523182/css-trapezoid-button-with-solid-border

Comment: thank you, guys. i fixed it at that time

Answer (score 1):

I've used skewed pseudo-element.
CSS:

```
.my_button {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, transparent 3.5rem, #F97300 3.5rem);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 12px;
    padding: .75em 1.25em .75em 2rem;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.my_button::before {
    content: '';
    background-color: #F97300;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px 0 12px 8px;
    transform: skewX(30deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

See [this pen](https://codepen.io/Rafiozoo/pen/GRyEryJ?editors=1100).