# HTML and CSS tricks to create Trapezium shapes

Tags: html, css

[I want to create this with HTML and CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S4kn.png)

[image: I want create this also with HTML and CSS]

I also want to be able to create the opposite shape of this image, I mean the sliced side will be facing the left. Thank you.

Comment: You can do this with `background`.

Comment: https://www.popwebdesign.net/drawing-unconventional-shapes-with-css.html

Comment: Thank you @MakwanaPrahlad. Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

A simple hacks would be instead of using CSS to create the shape, use an image.

Also there are similar question being asked, please refer [How to draw a trapezium/trapezoid with css3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920754/how-to-draw-a-trapezium-trapezoid-with-css3)